# How to fill a polygon in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

The Python code given below draws a triangle, how can I fill it with a color inside? Or another easier way to draw a triangle in OpenCV?

```
pts = np.array([[100,350],[165,350],[165,240]], np.int32)
cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(0,255,255),2)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to use `cv2.fillPoly()`.

**Illustration for 2-channeled image**

Change the second line to:

```
cv2.fillPoly(img, [pts], 255)
```

**Code:**

```
img = np.zeros([400, 400],dtype=np.uint8)
pts = np.array([[100,350],[165,350],[165,240]], np.int32)
cv2.fillPoly(img, [pts], 255)
cv2.imshow('Original', img)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Illustration for 3-channeled color image**

```
img = cv2.imread('image_path')
pts = np.array([[170,50],[240, 40],[240, 150], [210, 100], [130, 130]], np.int32)
cv2.fillPoly(img, [pts], (255,150,255))
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Just a small detail, the last parameter in fillPoly must be (255,255,255) to fill the polygon with white color, instead it will represent only Blue channel.