# How to fill a polygon using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to fill these polygon with white color and this operation is repeated through a loop over the whole image so I would like to know the syntax and function which can be used to perform this operation using opencv in python
This is my input image

[image]

```
alist=[]
img = cv2.imread('closing2.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
imo = cv2.imread('closing2.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
imr = cv2.imread('closing2.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)*0
imac = imr
height , width  = imo.shape[:2]
a,im = cv2.threshold(img,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# i=100
# p=[i,i]
points = []
for j in range(0,1000,50):
    for i in range(0,1000,50):
        p=[i,j]
        poly = raypoly(im,p,5)
        st = metrics(p,poly)

        polyc=raypolyLimit(im,p,st,30)
        # print(polyc)
        # print(len(polyc))
        # for m in range(len(polyc)):
        #     point = polyc[m]
        #     cv2.fillConvexPoly(im, point, 255)
        plotpoly(polyc,imr)

        plotpolypoints(polyc,imr,255,1)
        # plotray(im,p,imr)

        am = polyArea(polyc)
        # print(am)
        if am > 5:
            alist.append(am)
            # img[(i-5):(i+5),(j-5):(j+5)]=150
            # plt.imshow(imf)
            # plt.show()
        imo = im * 0
        plotpoly(polyc,imo)
        plotpoly(polyc, im)
        # plotArea(polyc,imo)
        imf = imo*1000 +im
        a,imf = cv2.threshold(imf,100.0,255.0,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imshow('Frame_1', imr)
        cv2.imshow('Frame_3', imo)
        cv2.imshow('Frame_4', imf)
        cv2.imshow('Frame_5', im)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I used the following function and the result as follows:

```
cv2.floodFill(imo,None,(i,j),255)
```

But my problem is that it gives a white flash for the whole image after certain number of polygons and I don't know how to fix it .

[image]

Comment: If you do not insist on using opencv, there is [scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes.html) for binary images

Comment: Are you provided with these empty polygons or do you create them on your own, e.g. using [`drawContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc)? If the latter, just set the `thickness` to `FILLED`. Otherwise, you may need to use [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) to find these polygons beforehand. (Then, you could also use [`floodFill`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0) for example.)

Comment: No these empty polygons were created on my own so I think that usinf floodfill or fillpoly would do this process but my problem is the mask used in this operation ??

Comment: @AhmedHabashi Then, please provide the code, which you use to create and draw the polygons [by editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57669562/edit). It's easier to suggest possible improvements than making up solutions de novo, which then might not fit your existing code.

Comment: @HansHirse OK I edited my question by posting part of my algorithm as the definition of these functions are more than 250 lines and its main function to draw a polygon surrounding a certain point

Comment: Why open and read the same file 3 times? You have the data in RAM already! Just copy the RAM, which is millions of times faster and doesn't annoy your disk drive.

Comment: @MarkSetchell OK but I don't know that this annoys disk drive .. I can take a copy of image img.copy()

Comment: I was maybe exaggerating about annoying the disk drive and the buffer cache subsystem, but hopefully you get what I meant. Just trying to help engineers not get into *"sub-optimal practices"* ;-)

Comment: @HansHirse Could u tell e the best syntax for the function that suits my algorithm to perform such process

Comment: @AhmedHabashi Unfortunately, you didn't provide a [mre]. Obviously, there are private methods in your code. The part with the actual drawing of the polygon seems most interesting here. Also, is the provided image the input or the output?

Comment: @HansHirse the provided image is an input one and I want to fill this polygon to be white and this process is repeated through the whole image as every point in the loop encloses a polygon surrounding it

Comment: @HansHirse Also I edited my question by providing the required output image and function used but I faced a problem of white flash appears in the image and I don't know what the mask entered is correct or no

Comment: If you get a full white image, then one of your polygons is not fully closed and the flood fill leaks out to fill the whole image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121978/how-to-fill-a-polyline-in-opencv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`cv2.drawContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) to fill in a contour. From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#drawcontours), if the `thickness` parameter is negative (`thickness=CV_FILLED` or `thickness=-1`) then the contours will be filled. For instance, to fill in a contour with white

```
cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
```

---

So the idea is to find the desired contour using `cv2.findContours()` then fill it in using `cv2.drawContours()`. For your image:

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. That solution is what I want