# How to determine between inner and outer contour with Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to have a polygon region of interest and would like to perform an object detection algorithm within this area.

For example, the user gives some points and I want to create a polygon with them in my code (like the red region) and I want to perform my object detection code inside the red region.

The question is how can I search for object within this area and how should I implement the if conditions for defining IN and OUT areas?

Is there any efficient way to implement this in Python?

[image]

Comment: To draw a polygon from a given set of points pass the points as an array to `cv2.polyline()` and get your polygon. You can mask the polygon region (ROI) over the original image using `cv2.bitwise_and()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121978/how-to-fill-a-polyline-in-opencv

Comment: @JeruLuke I don't want to draw it on my image, I want it to be a restriction for my "object recognition" algorithm. I don't know how to search for object within this area and how should I implement the if conditions for defining IN and OUT area

Comment: I am suggesting you to mask the desired ROI on the image and then perform object detection

Comment: take the bounding box of the polygon, do your algorithm on that ROI, then discard what's in the bb but not in the polygon. opencv has a function for point-in-polygon test... or "draw" the polygon as a boolean mask and simply test the pixel's "color" (boolean value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to differentiate between outer and inner contours. To determine what contours are IN and OUT, you can simply use contour hierarchy to differentiate between the two. Specifically, when using [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) you can use `cv2.RETR_TREE` to extract outer or inner contours. See [understanding contour hierarchies: how to distinguish between contours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095520/understanding-contour-hierarchies-how-to-distinguish-filled-circle-contour-and/60104796#60104796) for the full explanation. From the full topology map we are given, we can filter out the contours, the idea is that if a parent contour has inner contours, it means that it's an `OUT` contour and the child inside is the `IN` contour. Another case is if a contour has no inner child then we know it is an `IN` contour.

Here's an example to demonstrate:

Input image

[image]

Result

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Filter using contour hierarchy
cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
for component in zip(cnts, hierarchy):
    currentContour = component[0]
    currentHierarchy = component[1]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
    # Has inner contours which means it is IN
    if currentHierarchy[2] < 0:
        cv2.putText(image, 'IN', (x,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (36,255,12), 2)
    # No child which means it is OUT
    elif currentHierarchy[3] < 0:
        cv2.putText(image, 'OUT', (x,y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```